# I made my .exe create a .txt and call it again. working very well in .py but not working in .exe (Python)

Tags: python, tkinter, pyinstaller

I wrote a code (login system) where I stored passwords and username in a Google Sheet by gspread. I also wrote a feature (remember me) whose main function is to create a txt file and enter the login name and password in it. So that when the user opens the program again, the code calls this file and reads the data from it and then fills in the fields.

**in (.py)** Everything working very well .

**in (exe)** Everything is also working fine except writing data again from user inputs to the txt file

**more clarification:**
**-** When the user uses the app for the **first time**. The code creates a txt file in the same folder as the program . this step working fine

**-** When the user enters the login name and password. Then he presses on (remember me) then press enter , this step also working fine except (Write the user information in the txt file that app created before)

any help ? thanks

im using tkinter

Comment: I don't understand what's not working.  Are you saying the exe can't read the text file the second time?  Or are you saying it can't WRITE the text file a second time?  You should show us the source code.

Comment: when i convert py to exe ( --onedir ) its working fine and can read and write in the txt file or json whatever
but if i convert py to exe (--one file ) app cant write into txt but can read

Comment: How can we help you if we don't have any way to know where the problem is? You should create a minimal code example, that has the same problem otherwise nobody has the complete information to help you (we can only guess what common problems it could be).

Comment: Sorry guys its work now ,, when i run my exe file as adminstrator LOL , its works fine and app able to write data into txt file as normal ...
my problem was my app can read txt file but can write into it ,, thats it

Answer (score 0):

problem solved by Run my exe as adminstrator , so can write the login info into the file .